# Checking and Returning values from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this little issue:

I want to retrieve some rows from the database, it retrieves fine, but when i insert a particular value in the text field which is not present in the database to track, it returns an empty/blank page,  below is the code i used:

```
<form id="track" name="track" method="post" action="track_now.php"> 
        <h2>Track your shipment Here</h2>

      <p><label> Tracking Reference: 
      <input type="text" id="reference" name="reference" value="" maxlength="40" required="required" /></label></p>


      <div class="button_holder">

        <p>   <input type="submit" id="track" value="Track Now" maxlength="40" required="required" /></label>
      </label></p>

      </div>
</form>
```

and this is the track_now.php

```
<form id="track" name="track" method="post" action=""> 
        <h2>Your Shipment Result</h2>

            <?php
//error_reporting(0);
$ref = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reference']);

// conmnecting to the database
if(isset($ref))
{ 
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', "admin") or die(mysql_error("Cannot Connect to Database")); 
mysql_select_db('tracking') or die(mysql_error());

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_tracking WHERE ship_ref = '".$ref."' "; 

$rs  = mysql_query($sql);
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo '<table width="518" border="1";>'; 

         echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td width="137" style="font-size:12px; padding: 5px;" >Shipment Reference: </td>';
  echo '<td width="365" style="background-color:#fcfcfc; padding: 10px;  font-size:12px;">' . $row['ship_ref'] . "<br />" . '</td>'; 
 echo '</tr>';

     echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td width="137" style="font-size:12px; padding: 5px;" >Shipment Type: </td>';
 echo '<td width="365" style="background-color:#fcfcfc; padding: 10px;  font-size:12px;">' . $row['ship_type'] . "<br />" . '</td>'; 
 echo '</tr>';

}

echo "</table>";
}
else if ($rs != $row) {
print 'Invalid Tracking Number, Please <a href="tracking.php"> click here </a> to try  again' ;
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Please, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by insert a particular value into a field that isn't present in the database?

Comment: use mysqli or PDO .. mysql_functions are no longer maintained. Also, you are not closing your form like so: </form>

Comment: I don't see a form element named "reference". Nor do I see a closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, and `or die(mysql_error($db))` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Hello all, thank you for the response. this is the scenario. a user comes to the site to track something. he inserts a reference and click on track, the ref number  returns the rows from the database. which works fine, but i want a situation whereby if a wrong number is inserted, a warning message like: Invalid number/wrong number should pop up. I have editted the code which includes the form element. also, i have closed the form and no changes..how and where do i use the PDO object?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition could be simplified, try this way:

```
if(isset($ref)){ 
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', "admin") or die(mysql_error("Cannot Connect to Database")); 
    mysql_select_db('tracking') or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_tracking WHERE ship_ref = '".$ref."' "; 
    $rs  = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!rs){
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        echo '<table width="518" border="1";>'; 

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="137" style="font-size:12px; padding: 5px;" >Shipment Reference: </td>';
        echo '<td width="365" style="background-color:#fcfcfc; padding: 10px;  font-size:12px;">' . $row['ship_ref'] . "<br />" . '</td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="137" style="font-size:12px; padding: 5px;" >Shipment Type: </td>';
        echo '<td width="365" style="background-color:#fcfcfc; padding: 10px;  font-size:12px;">' . $row['ship_type'] . "<br />" . '</td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';
        echo "</table>";
    }
    mysql_close();
}
else{
    print 'Invalid Tracking Number, Please <a href="tracking.php"> click here </a> to try  again' ;
}
```

because `else if ($rs != $row)` will have undefined value if first condition is not met.

As @marco pointed out, you can check for rows without fetching:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0){
  //found a row
}
```

Comment: Hello all, thank you for the response. this is the scenario. a user comes to the site to track something. he inserts a reference and click on track, the ref number returns the rows from the database. which works fine, but i want a situation whereby if a wrong number is inserted, a warning message like: Invalid number/wrong number should pop up. I have edited the code which includes the form element. also, i have closed the form and still no changes..how and where do i use the PDO object? when i use else, dreamweaver gave me code hint error.

Comment: Out of curiosity why did you disappear for 9 hours right after posting question here \?

Comment: hello @Meda, thanks for the codes, unfortunately, the codes throws an Use of undefined constant rs - assumed 'rs' in C:\wamp error.

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: @AdenijiOlasunkanmi I missed the dollar sign, I trust you that you can correct my small typos

Comment: I am so sorry @meda, whe i posted the question, it was already 10:37pm here, so i slept off. the time difference is killing. its 7:07am here now.. It was not intentional for me to disappear, i just cant cheat nature.. please accept my apology.

Comment: fix the variable with `$rs`

Comment: I added the $ sign, but its still showing/returning a blank page at the tester.php file..what other trick could be employed?

Comment: I have no idea what `tester.php` is, the one you posted is called `track_now.php`

Comment: sorry, i was referring to track_now.php..

please run that code and see if it works from your end.. thanks !

Comment: the code I gave you should either, print the table or that line: `Invalid Tracking Number ...`

Comment: its not, its giving me blank page !