# Show the table if only there is a record found

Tags: php, html

What I mean is when there is a record found from the select result, the table is show up. But when there is no record, I don't want to show the table, but maybe with else statement.

I use this code:

```
       <?php
       $referenceNumber = $_POST['referenceNumber'];
       $result = $mysqli->query ("SELECT anything what I want

       if ($result > 0) {
         echo '<table id="orderHistoryTable" width=100% border=1 style="text-align:center">';                                
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>ITEMS</td>';
         echo '<td>QUANTITY</td>';
         echo '<td>Infistall Location</td>';
         echo '<td>Infistall Address</td>';
         echo '</tr>';
          while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td>'.$obj->items.'</td>';
             echo '<td>'.$obj->esquantity.'</td>';
             echo '<td>'.$obj->infistall_Location.'</td>';
             echo '<td>'.$obj->infistall_address.'</td>';
             echo '</tr>';
           }
             echo '<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
                       <td><input type="submit" /></td>
                   </tr>';
        }

      ?>
     </table>
```

I have replace the way I echo it. Sometimes it loops the table. And with the code above it doesn't loop the table, but it shows the first `<tr>...</tr>` of the column title.

Thanks for easily understand my problem.

Comment: do a `var_dump($return)` to see what type `$return` is, might not be what you think and equate to something greater than zero

Answer (score 1):

use

```
if($results->num_rows === 0)
{
   echo 'No results';
}
else
{
echo '<table id="orderHistoryTable" width=100% border=1 style="text-align:center">';                                
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>ITEMS</td>';
         echo '<td>QUANTITY</td>';
         echo '<td>Infistall Location</td>';
         echo '<td>Infistall Address</td>';
         echo '</tr>';
          while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td>'.$obj->items.'</td>';
             echo '<td>'.$obj->esquantity.'</td>';
             echo '<td>'.$obj->infistall_Location.'</td>';
             echo '<td>'.$obj->infistall_address.'</td>';
             echo '</tr>';
           }
             echo '<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
                       <td><input type="submit" /></td>
                   </tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use **mysqli_num_rows** check results

for example you can use

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
     echo "<table>"
else
     echo "No results found";
```

Comment: actually I use `SELECT something From onething where anything LIKE everything` which it means that I am searching for a result. The code you give is achieving what I need, but the echo in `else` statment is showing up before I do searching for the `keyword`.

Comment: I don't understand issue can you please eleborate properly ? 
actually **else** statement will be execute when no records found.

Answer (score 1):

You are right just us else statement like this

```
<?php
   $referenceNumber = $_POST['referenceNumber'];
   $result = $mysqli->query ("SELECT anything what I want");

   echo '<table id="orderHistoryTable" width=100% border=1 style="text-align:center">';                                
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>ITEMS</td>';
   echo '<td>QUANTITY</td>';
   echo '<td>Infistall Location</td>';
   echo '<td>Infistall Address</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
   if ($result > 0) {

      while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'.$obj->items.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$obj->esquantity.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$obj->infistall_Location.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$obj->infistall_address.'</td>';
         echo '</tr>';
       }
         echo '<tr><td colspan="2"></td>
                   <td><input type="submit" /></td>
               </tr>';
    } else {
       echo '<tr><td colspan="4">NO Records Found</td></tr>';
    }

  ?>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

and if condition be like:

```
if ($row_cnt > 0)
```

[**mysqli_num_rows**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

Put your end tag  within if statement (within curly brace }). It should be within the same if statement as .

Answer (score 0):

We asked almost the same question.

check here: [Checking and Returning values from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258868/checking-and-returning-values-from-database)

and see if it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code definitely work.

```
<?php
echo '<table id="orderHistoryTable" width=100% border=1 style="text-align:center">';         
$referenceNumber = $_POST['referenceNumber'];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT anything what I want");
if($result->num_rows() > 0){                       
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>ITEMS</td>';
            echo '<td>QUANTITY</td>';
            echo '<td>Infistall Location</td>';
            echo '<td>Infistall Address</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
                while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$obj->items.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$obj->esquantity.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$obj->infistall_Location.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$obj->infistall_address.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        echo '<tr><td colspan="3"></td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr>';
} else {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4">NO Records Found</td></tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
?>
```